# Как сделать вызов модального окна, при клике на ссылку, внутри балуна яндекс карты JSAPI 2.1?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, как при клике по одной из ссылок, находящихся внутри балуна яндекс карты JSAPI 2.1, открывать модальное окно?
**Метки буду создавать через ObjectManager:**
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, 
    "properties": {"balloonContent": "<font size=2><b><a class='gallery' title='Простая HTML' href='/images/1_b.jpg'>Клик</a></b></font><br><font size=2><b><a target='_blank' href='#'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка 2</a></b></font><br><font size=2><b><a target='_blank' href='#'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка 3</a></b></font>","clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}}
]
```

}

Пробовал разные методы: Bootstrap Modal, FancyBox.
Дошел до того что ошибок в консоли нет, но все равно не работает.
Я в этой теме новичок. Прошу сильно не ругать.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не про JS API. Навскидку, проверьте [порядок обработки событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-timing-depth). Для дебага нужен будет полный пример вашего кода.